# Listbox binding in Silverlight

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0, listbox

I have a listbox on silverlight page, the datacontext of the page is set to an instance -- **TestQuestions**, please see the code below. The listbox uses a DataTemplate and its ItemSource is '**Answers**' which is a property of the page's DataContext, everything works fine until I try to bind to '**ShowAnswer**', a property on the page's DataContext within the DataTemplate.  No matter what I tried it won't pick the property's value.

Thank you all for your help.

Xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Answers, Mode=TwoWay}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=Correct, Mode=TwoWay}" >
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowAnswer}">
                    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Visibility="{Binding Path=Correct}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AnswerText, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </Grid>
        </RadioButton>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

C#:

```
public class Answer
{
    private bool correct = false;
    public bool Correct
    {
        get { return correct; }
        set
        {
            correct = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Correct");
        }
    }

    private string answerText = false;
    public string AnswerText
    {
        get { return answerText; }
        set
        {
            answerText = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("AnswerText");

        }
    }

}



public class TestQuestions
{
    private ObservableCollection<Answer> answers = new ObservableCollection<Answer>();
    public ObservableCollection<Answer> Answers
    {
        get { return answers; }
        set
        {
            if (answers != value)
            {
                answers = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Answers");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool showAnswer = false;
    public bool ShowAnswer
    {
        get { return showAnswer; }
        set
        {
            showAnswer = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ShowAnswer");
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're trying to bind the UIElement.Visibility to a boolean value.  Change your 'ShowAnswer' property from a boolean to a Visibility property and you should be set.

```
private Visibility showAnswer = Visibility.Collapsed; 
public Visibility ShowAnswer 
{ 
    get { return showAnswer; } 
    set 
    { 
        showAnswer = value; 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ShowAnswer"); 
    } 
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you are trying to bind to a property on the DataContext of the parent control, you could do this:

Name your UserControl

Example:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MvvmLightProto.MainPage"
         x:Name="mainProtoPage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         Height="700"
         Width="1200">
```

In the above example, the UserControl has the name of "mainProtoPage", now in your XAML, you could do this:

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding DataContext.ShowAnswer, ElementName=mainProtoPage}">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. the main problem is that I cannot bind to a property that is not declared within the ItemSource object. As for the Visibility being bound to a boolean value, I am actually using a converter it's left out of the code.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I have edited my answer, I think it's what you are looking for now.

Comment: Thanks again for your response JSprang. What of a situation where the template is declared in a Resource file? I tried using the using the class name of the Page where the resource file is being used but it didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: Don't use the x:Class name, use the x:Name.  In my example, I used mainProtoPage because my x:Name="mainProtoPage".